# Howto make sure NSOperationQueue is really empty

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In my application I add concurrent operations to my NSOperationQeueu by looping over an array of files that I want to do some operation on. I want to know when the queue is empty and all of the operations have finished so I use (shortened down version):

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

        if (object == myLocalModeController.myFileobjectsQueue && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"]) {


        if ([myLocalModeController.myFileobjectsQueue.operations count] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Local: Fileobject creation has completed");  
          }
        }
     }
```

My problem is that sometimes the operations are so lightweight that they finish immediately while the queue is still being added to. This results in frequent occurrences where the number of items in the queue is zero, but the operations have not finished. However, based on my current setup the program thinks that the operations have finished since '[myLocalModeController.myFileobjectsQueue.operations count] == 0'. Any suggestions for how to make sure that the queue really is finished and that all operations have ended? Thanks. Cheers, Trond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to block all operations while you are adding them using setSuspended:

```
- (void)setSuspended:(BOOL)suspend;
```

So before adding all operation you set it to YES, and when you've finished you set it to NO.

Comment: Good answer. Or Trond could just add a global "still setting up" flag, or another property like "configuringOperations".